# Why dict not being updated in python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Please check below code.

I initialized a dict and send it to a function f. I checked the address of return_dict. It is not changing inside the process. So I thought the dict should be updated

**But it is not updated, so why?**

```
from multiprocessing import Process

return_dict = dict({})
print id(return_dict)


def f(value, return_dict):
    return_dict['value'] = value
    print return_dict


p = Process(target=f, args=(100, return_dict))
p.start()
p.join()
print return_dict
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Process()` creates another process. It inherits objects as they are from your parent process when the child process is spawned, but modifications to these objects only modify the objects in child process memory and none of these changes are visible to parent.

You can overcome this by using `Manager()`:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def f(value, return_dict):
    return_dict['value'] = value
    print return_dict

d = Manager().dict()    
p = Process(target=f, args=(100, d))
p.start()
p.join()
print d
```

Comment: But the memory address of return_dict is not changing. How to explain that? If they are different objects the address should not be the same I think. If they are the same object then the change should be visable to parent process

Comment: I would assume the memory address is relative to process memory space, not an absolute address within the computer's memory.  If your object in parent process is in location X of the heap, then when a child is spawned, it will receive one to one copy of this. The object address is still at X, even though it is a different process and different memory segment within the computer. Your child process would not have access to parent process memory anyway as it would cause a segmentation fault.